# How to add "$" string to an interpolated value?

Tags: css, sass, interpolation

say I want to produce `$small` by adding an interpolated value to '$', or, in other words, by concatenating the string '$' to an interpolated value. Something like this:

```
$#{value}
```

or this:

```
"$" + #{value}
```

None of them seem to work in sass/scss. Is there a working syntax for this?

I need this because I'm building this mixin that accept media queries names (it comes from my framework, too long to explain, and a little offtopic) and I'd like to strip out the dollar when passing arguments:

```
@mixin prog-prop($property-name, $mq-values){
  @each $mq in $mq-values{
    @include mq(#{nth($mq, 1)}){ #{$property-name}: #{nth($mq, 2)} }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: added explanation, though i think it's quite useless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do so, but this is a way:

```
$value:'string';

$value: '$#{$value}';

.value{
  content: $value;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's applicable to my use case, see above.

Comment: Still incomplete question. Undefined mq function. I don't understand what are you trying, sry.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is described above: produce `$small` by adding an interpolated value to '$', or, in other words, by concatenating the string '$' to an interpolated value.